# JQuery image slider works wierdly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have pasted ready-to-use code to implement image slider functionality on my website. Slider works but not the way it should be. It is not static (images change on the same spot), but images jump to the right. What have i done wrong? I would appreciate any help.

Code

```js
  

$(function() {
    var image = $("#slider img");
    var numSlides = image.length;
    var activeSlide = 0;
    var speed = 2000;
    var fade = 1000;
    var timer = setInterval(rotate, speed);
    image.eq(activeSlide).show();
      
    function rotate() {
        activeSlide++;
      
     if (activeSlide == numSlides) {
            activeSlide = 0;
      }

      
     image.not(activeSlide).fadeOut(fade);
     image.eq(activeSlide).fadeIn(fade);
      }
    });
```

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Vesper+Libre:400,500,700,900&subset=devanagari,latin-ext';

.navbar {
  background-color:#bcaaa4;
  height:100px;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  border:none;
  /*border-bottom:1px solid black;*/
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.navbar-right li a {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size:18px;
  color: #efebe9 !important;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

#buy-it-now a {
  border:2px solid #efebe9;
  border-radius:50px;
}

a.navbar-brand  {
  /*background-color:red;*/
  padding:0;
  width:100px;
  height:100%;
}

#logo-img {
  padding-top:0;
  width:100px;
}

/*********** UPPER SECTION ************/
.upper-section-central-content {
  /*background-color:red;*/
  margin-top:120px;
  height:auto;
}

#upper-sec-img-wrapper img {
  width:400px;
}

#upper-sec-img-wrapper {
  width:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.upper-section {
  padding-top:0 !important;
  background-color:#bcaaa4;
}

#upper-sec-words-wrapper {
  margin-top:120px;
  text-align:center;
  /*background-color:red;*/
}
#upper-sec-words-wrapper p:first-child{
  font-family:"Roboto";
  font-size:30px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#efebe9;
}

#upper-sec-words-wrapper p:nth-child(2){
  font-family:"Raleway";
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:light;
  color:#efebe9;
}

/******MIDDLE SECTION*******/

.middle-section {
  background-color:#e5dfdc;
}

.mid-sec-words p {
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:70px;
  font-family:"Raleway";
  font-weight:Medium;
  font-size:30px;
  color:#d7c3e5;
}

.mid-sec-img {
  margin-top:50px;
  /*background-color:red;*/
  height:auto;
}

.inner-img {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:300px;
}

.inner-img-center {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:500px;
}

.first-fox {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:200px;
}

.inner-img img {
  padding-top:20px;
  width:100%;
}

.inner-img-center img {
  padding-top:30px;
  width:100%;
}

.gallery {
  background-color:#e5dfdc;
}
.gallery .col-md-8 {
  background-color:red;
  height:400px;
}

.gallery .col-md-4 {
  background-color:blue;
  height:400px;
}





/***** Make text responsive *****/

@media all and (max-width: 2000px) { 
/* screen size until 1200px */
  
    navbar-nav li a {
        font-size: 18px; /* 1.5x default size */
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1600px) { 
/* screen size until 1200px */
  
    navbar-nav li a {
        font-size: 18px; /* 1.5x default size */
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1200px) { 
/* screen size until 1200px */
  
    navbar-nav li a {
        font-size: 18px; /* 1.5x default size */
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1000px) { /* screen size until 1000px */
  
    navbar-nav li a {
        font-size: 18px; /* 1.5x default size */
    }
  
    #upper-sec-words-wrapper {
        margin-top:180px;
    }
  
    #buy-it-now a {
    border:none;
    }
  
  }
@media all and (max-width: 500px) { /* screen size until 500px */
    navbar-nav li a {
        font-size: 18px; /* 1.5x default size */
    }
  
    #upper-sec-img-wrapper img {
          width:300px;
        }
  
    #upper-sec-words-wrapper p:first-child{
      font-family:"Roboto";
      font-size:24px;
      font-weight:bold;
      color:#efebe9;
    }

    #upper-sec-words-wrapper p:nth-child(2){
      font-family:"Raleway";
      font-size:12px;
      font-weight:light;
      color:#efebe9;
    }
    .mid-sec-words p {
      font-size:24px;
    }
  
    .inner-img-center img {
      width:60%;
    }
  
    .inner-img img {
      width:80%;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo-img" src="http://www.fillfox.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/FILL-FOX-LOGO-ONLY3A-1024x1024.png"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Species</a></li>
        <li id="buy-it-now"><a href="#">Buy it now</a></li>
        
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<section class="upper-section">

<div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">
    
      <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-12" id="upper-sec-words-wrapper">
          <p>“Sweet, Beautiful and Dangerous”</p>
          <p>ADOPT THE MOST GORGEOUS FOXES TO EMBOLISH YOUR SETTING</p>
        </div>

      </row> <!--end of inside row-->
    
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-12 upper-section-central-content">
      
        <div id="upper-sec-img-wrapper">
          <img class="img-responsive" id="upper-section-img" src="http://pngimg.com/upload/fox_PNG370.png">
          
        </div>
      
    </div> <!--end of col-md-6-->
    
  </div> <!--end of row-->
  
</div><!-- /.container -->
  
</section> <!--UPPER-SECTION-->


<section class="middle-section">
  
  <div class="container">
    
    <div class="row">
      
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-12 mid-sec-words">
        
        <p>Look how pretty they are!</p>
        
      </div> <!--end mid-sec-words-->
      
    </div> <!--end row-->
    
    <div class="row">
      
      <div class="col-md-4 mid-sec-img">
        
        <div class="inner-img first-fox">
          
          <img src="http://t06.deviantart.net/SYKQBb0tWScCRv1RHCj-beynIdY=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre15/1d3c/th/pre/i/2011/148/4/d/fox_lineart_by_neonmars-d3hf06q.png">
          
        </div>
        
      </div> <!--mid-sec-img-->
      
      <div class="col-md-4 mid-sec-img">
        
          <div class="inner-img">

              <img src="https://orig03.deviantart.net/bd8b/f/2016/002/4/3/free_to_use___fox_base_by_maonii-d9mge7j.png">

          </div>
      
      </div> <!--mid-sec-img-->
      
      <div class="col-md-4 mid-sec-img">
        
          <div class="inner-img">

                <img src="http://orig12.deviantart.net/cc3f/f/2013/186/f/8/free_new_fox_lines_by_galianogangster-d6c638n.png">

          </div>
      
      </div> <!--mid-sec-img-->
      
    </div> <!--end row-->
    
    <div class="row">
      
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-12">
        <div class="inner-img-center">
          <img src="http://orig01.deviantart.net/80a2/f/2015/283/e/7/_cm__red_fox_by_cylithren-d9cmeb6.gif">
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div> <!--row-->
    
  <div>  <!--container-->
  
</section> <!--middle-section-->
    
<section class="gallery">
  
  
  <div class="container">
    
    <div class="row">
      
      <div class="col-md-8">
        
        <div id="slider">
          
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200?image=1">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200?image=2">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200?image=3">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200?image=4">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200?image=5">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200?image=6">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200?image=7">
          
        </div> <!--slider-->
        
      </div> <!--col-md-8-->
      
      <div class="col-md-4">
        
      </div>
      
    </div> <!--row-->
  </div> <!--container-->
  
  
</section>
```

Comment: Probably because two slides are being loaded at the same time, and so appear next to each other until the first one disappears. I think you should load all of them at once, and use absolute positioning. THen you can fade between them, whilst they stay in the same place.

Comment: You did not need to include all of your website code. BTW if I understand correctly, the images should fade out and fade in? Because that is not *sliding* per se

Answer (score 0):

Lee was right i positioned images to absolute, not it works fine. By the way how can i stretch images so that they cover the whole div (col-md-8)? Like on the image. I tries to set width of the slider div to 100% and images to 100% either, but images overflow parent div.

[image]